# How to put a constraint on composite primary key, so its attributes are always different from one another?

Tags: database-design

I have a composite primary key with the attributes: (departure_airport, arrival_airport) and I was wondering if there is some kind of constraint to make sure the departure_airport is not the same with the arrival_airport?

Comment: This kind of question might be better asked on sister site DBA.StackExchange.com

Comment: What version of what DBMS?

Comment: When you were researching & you read any introduction whatsoever to constraints, what seemed relevant? Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

Being a composite key is irrelevant.

You need to apply a `CHECK` constraint or write a trigger that compares the two fields for equality.